# Azure AD, InTune, TeamViewer

Tags: azure, teamviewer, entra-domain-services, microsoft-intune

So I had come across [This Article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jeffgilb/2016/09/02/enrolling-windows-10-pcs-as-mobile-devices-with-intune/) explaining it is better to manage Windows 10 devices as mobile devices rather than using the InTune console, which I have already done. Most of our machine are laptops anyway.

I was debating on getting TeamViewer and leveraging the InTune compatibility however it appears that TeamViewer will only work with the InTune desktop client installed. Is this the case? Are there plans to extend this feature to corporate owned mobile managed devices?

Comment: Sounds like a question that should be directed at Teamviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeamViewer is a third party tool that can work individually without Microsoft Intune. You are probably asking about [The TeamViewer integration for Microsoft Intune](https://integrate.teamviewer.com/en/integrate/intune/). The more detailed [TechNet article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-classic/deploy-use/common-windows-pc-management-tasks-with-the-microsoft-intune-computer-client) confirms your suspects:

> This topic lists tasks you can do to manage desktops that you manage
>   as PCs by installing the Intune software client. This topic does not
>   cover managing PCs as mobile devices.

However, if you have a license to TeamViewer, you could use the standard version without integration. As a customer you get access to .msi installer for [easier deployment](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Deploy-TeamViewer-Host-MSI-Package-with-Assignment-Tool/ta-p/310). A bit tricky is to collect the IDs, and the best way depends on both overall configuration and company practices.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Microsoft's [Quick Assist](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20534/windows-10-quick-assist-faq) will authenticate using Azure AD, we may some day switch to using it. There are two things holding us back, however; the authentication does not work correctly on machines joined to the local domain and it does not handle UAC prompting. There is a [related UserVoice suggestion](https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com/forums/291681-ideas/suggestions/19720282-integrate-the-windows-10-quick-assist-app-with-int), to vote on, asking for Quick Assist to be integrated into Intune.

Until then, our solution has been to "Design & Deploy" a custom module in the TeamViewer management console and to install the TeamViewer Host on our Windows Devices using an Intune Device Configuration Powershell script. We edit and upload [the following script, Install-TeamViewer.ps1](https://gist.github.com/treestryder/6f608b7a73fe81157633145e42cad2b2), with the custom module Config ID and API key.